# Unable to get dedupe records with rank

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, rank

I am trying to dedupe my dataset using rank, but it is not assigning a different number to the second record. What am I doing wrong here?

```
with get_rank as (
                    select id, code, rank() over (partition by id order by z.rowid) as ranking
                    from mytable z                          
                 ) 
select * 
from get_rank
where ranking = 1
and id = 72755





        ID CODE    RANKING
---------- ---- ----------
     72755 M             1
     72755 M             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
with get_rank as (
      select id, code,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by z.rowid) as ranking
     from mytable z                          
    ) 
select * 
from get_rank
where ranking = 1 and id = 72755;
```

It is guaranteed to return a different value for each row.